# What is the default Kotlin language version per Kotlin release?

Tags: kotlin

While looking at the ["What's new" of Kotlin 1.7.20](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew1720.html#preview-of-the-operator-for-creating-open-ended-ranges), I see that I need to set the Kotlin language version to 1.8 if I want to use the latest features.

So far, I have never set the language version. What is the default value of Kotlin language version per Kotlin release? And where is it documented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The language version is the release version.

For your specific example, the documentation queries `1.8` because it is an *experimental* feature. It means that the current release (`1.7.20`) does **not** ship/accept this feature for stable builds.

Therefore, you have to ask the compiler to activate features planned for the next Kotlin release, i.e `1.8`.

Compiler [`-language-version` option](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/compiler-reference.html#language-version-version) can serve to activate experimental features, <del>but also in the other way: to prevent using features introduced after a specific version</del>.

**EDIT** :

Originally, I stated that the `-language-version` argument could be given an older version, to help maintaining a certain version compatibility (which can be important for the community), and still benefit from bugfixes and performance improvements of newly released compilers.

**But** It appears I was wrong, It looks like the `language-version` option is really designed for experimental feature, not much for backward language compatibility. In [the following Youtrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-25823/Report-a-warning-or-error-if-an-old-language-version-or-API-version-is-used), they mention that the compiler should raise a warning if `language-version` is set to an old language version.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. So unless I want to test an experimental feature, I never need to set the language version explicitly.